# Not well recognised in the team work, how to improve that?

Tags: company-culture, teamwork, competition

I was the key player in my team and contribute significant amount to the team work. Actually I solve the most tough part of the work for the team. But I am not well recognized as an individual and an award is given to the team and my boss likes to say "Well done team" always.

I want to improve my situation and position in the team and gain recognition that I deserved in my future career. Seeking advice here.

Comment: Does your company have performance reviews periodically? Are the parts each team member contributes to documented and visible?

Comment: @DarkCygnus We did have annual performance reviews and everyone clearly knows who did what in a project. But in my company culture and politics, the boss/manager only want to mention the entire team rather than any individual

Comment: I see... then you should check my answer, I feel there is nothing to worry about. Your manager is simply being polite and fair by congratulating all the members of the team... congratulating only you or only one would not be motivating and generate discord between the team

Comment: @DarkCygnus Actually I can't put all the story online and let people know the real story that happen on me. I have strong evidence that my contribution was underestimated and I just want to seek an efficient way to communicate with my manager and help me gain more individual recognition afterwards.

Comment: Does your boss acknowledge your contributions in private, in 1:1s and performance reviews? Does this reflect in your title and salary?

Comment: The fact that he says “well done team” doesn’t mean he doesn’t recognize your individual contribution. It’s a pretty normal thing for a manager to say.

Comment: @Llewellyn This is the reason why I feel I was not well recognised. Actually I didn't get any rewards on either my title or my salary increase.

Answer (score 5):

> But I am not well recognized as an individual and an award is given to the team and my boss likes to say "Well done team" always.

I can't help feel that what you are saying is *"I don't get all the credit, how can I get all the credit?"*.

At the end of the day, this is still a team and teamwork: you don't do the 100% of the tasks and parts of the project, so technically you don't deserve *"all"* the credit.

In your place, I would be happy that my team received an award, and is constantly praised for the results *we* deliver. I would be especially happy/proud if I did the hard work.

**I am completely sure that your manager is aware of your contributions to the project.** However, a good manager will praise and congratulate the whole team, mainly because (1) the reasons exposed above (you didn't do 100% of the tasks) and because (2) praising only one member would generate discord and rift in the team, and would be something demotivating for the rest of the team.

> I want to improve my situation and position in the team and gain recognition that I deserved in my future career. Seeking advice here.

If your company has performance reviews, and on the projects you work it is documented what and where each member contributes, then you should not worry about this; it is known and can be looked up who did most of the work on the excellent projects (and on the bad projects as well...).

It will be obvious for anyone looking at the repository commit logs who did what, and what part of the code/project each one contributed. These sort of things are considered for evaluation and performance reviews, and *will* reflect positively on you, your possible promotions, recommendations, raises, etc..

Comment: If there exists a way that an outstanding team member gain his credit that matches his contribution from the team work if the manager just want to praise the whole team?

Comment: @LUSAQX hmm.. this has me thinking... I'll try to morph your question a bit so we can discuss further: *Could it be that your team is full of members that do the minimum or are not competent, thus you end up with the hard parts?*

Comment: yes, that is my situation. I was assigned to the most tough part of the technical problems and for that tough part, there were never any team work there. I solved the whole tough part. So my contribution is obvious and easy to prove.

Answer (score 2):

> But I am not well recognized as an individual and an award is given to the team and my boss likes to say "Well done team" always.

If you feel like you went above and beyond your normal role but aren't being recognized for it publicly on the team, it's worth talking to your manager about it. I would approach your manager for feedback on your contributions to the project in question.

Your manager may not be fully aware of your contributions especially if you do a lot of behind the scenes work. Or on the flip side, your contributions may not be as big as you believe if you aren't fully aware of all of the work that was done for the project. It could be that your manager wants to praise the whole team, because it was a team effort, but will take care of you during the performance review time. It's really hard to tell.

At the end of the day, it's worth a conversation with your manager to understand what's happening.